# Collapse PageBlockSection by default on page load

Tags: apex, visualforce

This script works well if you are not using the `<apex:repeat`

```
<script>
twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.pb.pbs}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])    
</script>
```

Using with `<apex:repeat` does not work, I able to duplicate and here is the code:

How to collapse the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` on page load? I'm getting a `null` below is the code:

VFP:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="repeatCon">
  <apex:form >  
    <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
           <apex:pageBlock title="hiding pb" mode="edit " id="pb">
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="my title" columns="1" id="pbs"  > 
                    some text here...
                </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            </apex:pageBlock> 
     </apex:repeat>

     <script>
         twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.pb.pbs}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])    
    </script>


    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class repeatCon {

    public PageReference createNewJobDetailBtn() {
        return null;
    } 
    public String[] getStrings() {
      return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};

    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: not sure i understand

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery in your forms? Ref: http://jquery.com/

Comment: yes if i need to then i can use jquery

Comment: in your repeat `<apex:pageBlock` generates each time so I think all the `apex:pageBlock` having same id that's why it is not working..

Comment: first i thought the same but how will you pass an repeat id to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause of not working, I was not passing the Id.

Here is the working solution:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".thePanel" ).each(function( index ) {
        twistSection(document.getElementById(this.id).getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
    });
  });  
</script>
```